# Using symbolic links to organize data without actually changing locations?

Tags: python, symlink, directory-structure

So I'm building a pipeline that is not going into a real production environment. Basically, I have some data in a defined folder structure, and I want to access it from different stages in my pipeline. Right now, data is ordered kind of like this

```
.../data/03-14-2019/unprocessed/raw/student_id_12345-raw.csv
```

or

```
.../data/05-04-2020/processed/position/student_id_1234345-position.csv
```

Now, I wrote a modular pipeline that looks in a folder and runs the pipeline all the .csv files in all the contained directories. If I point it at `.../data/03-14-2019/unprocessed/raw/` then my pipeline will process all of the raw data for every student. I built this under the assumption that we were going to rename all the files to a more manageable schema, but things may have changed. My question is this: Using the `os.link()` functionality in python3, would it be possible to make an alternate filepath system that includes what I want? For example, one way I may want to go through files might be:

```
.../data/unprocessed/student_id_12345/2019/03/14/raw/student_id_12345-raw.csv
```

or maybe

```
.../data/unprocessed/raw/2019/03/14/student_id_12345/student_id_12345-raw.csv
```

depending on if I want to process a certain batch of students or only raw data from a certain day. I remember using a batch renaming tool as part of either Total Commander or Nautilus, but I don't remember if it could do symbolic links. Basically, I want to use symbolic links to build a directory structure on top of an existing structure.

I was going to try implementing this, but I figured I should check if anyone has already done this or there were already solutions before I started, as well as maybe some suggestions of where to start. Thanks!

Comment: It seems like you're asking two different questions here: first the explicit question, "Can I use `os.link()` to do this?", then the implicit question, "Has anyone already done this?". Could you please [edit] to clarify? It'd help to make the title an actual question instead of a sentence fragment with a question mark at the end. See [ask] for tips.

Comment: `os.link()` creates **hard** links. For soft links (symlinks), use [`os.symlink()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.symlink).

Comment: I forgot to mention, keep in mind that tool recommendations are [off-topic](/help/on-topic) on SO unless you've already looked extensively and haven't found anything that fits your specific requirements.

Comment: FWIW, a third option is to do it on the fly: pass `.../data` to the pipeline along with parameters for date, student ID and processed/unprocessed and have it search for the matching CSV files. Assuming the path schema is standardized, ofc.

Comment: Yeah, I wish it was a little more standardized than it is. I'll look more into some tools, I haven't found anything yet. And yes, I guess it's two questions, but the more important one is "does there exist a way to do this alread"

Comment: I kinda doubt you're going to find a readymade solution cause it seems so easy to script it. Either way, you'd still have to write out the transformations yourself, like `month, day, year = path.parts[2].split('-'); ...; result = Path(..., year, month, day, ...)`